# If depth=TRUE, columns of leaves are stated to the left of dash,what is the meaning of those numbers?

Tags: r, depth

```
library(aplpack)
stem.leaf(rivers,depth=TRUE)

1 | 2: represents 120


 leaf unit: 10
            n: 141

    1     1 | 3
   29     2 | 0111133334555556666778888899    
   64     3 | 00000111122223333455555666677888999    
  (18)    4 | 011222233344566679    
   59     5 | 000222234467    
   47     6 | 0000112235789    
   34     7 | 12233368    
   26     8 | 04579    
   21     9 | 0008    
   17    10 | 035        
   14    11 | 07    
   12    12 | 047    
    9    13 | 0

HI: 1450 1459 1770 1885 2315 2348 2533 3710
```

What is the meaning of left side numbers(1st column from left)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/aplpack/versions/1.3.2/topics/stem.leaf) is not clear here, saying merely that it prints the depths, but not explaining what is meant by that. The idea is that you look at the sorted data. "Deeper" data is data that lies closer to the middle of the data. This depth is measured to the closest edge of the data. For example, if you look at `sort(rivers)` you get:

```
[1]  135  202  210  210  215  217  230  230  233  237  246  250  250  250  255
 [16]  259  260  260  265  268  270  276  280  280  280  281  286  290  291  300
 [31]  300  300  301  306  310  310  314  315  320  325  327  329  330  332  336
 [46]  338  340  350  350  350  350  352  360  360  360  360  375  377  380  380
 [61]  383  390  390  392  407  410  411  420  420  424  425  430  431  435  444
 [76]  445  450  460  460  465  470  490  500  500  505  524  525  525  529  538
 [91]  540  545  560  570  600  600  600  605  610  618  620  625  630  652  671
[106]  680  696  710  720  720  730  735  735  760  780  800  840  850  870  890
[121]  900  900  906  981 1000 1038 1054 1100 1171 1205 1243 1270 1306 1450 1459
[136] 1770 1885 2315 2348 2533 3710
```

The first depth of 1 corresponds to the fact that the first row `1 | 3` corresponds to the first river. The depth of 29 for the second row corresponds that there are 1 + 28 = 29 observations included in the first two rows. The final depth of `9` corresponds to the fact that the row `13 | 0` corresponds to the river `1306` which is 9 rivers in from the *right* of the data (with the 8 larger rivers given in `HI`.

The data containing the middle of the data presents a bit of a dilemma -- do you measure the depth from the left or from the right? The solution chosen here is to do neither, but instead simply give the count of the data at that depth. If you look at the three depths that straddle this medium: `64, (18), 59` you see that `64 + 18 + 59 = 141`, which is the number of observations.

Whether or not this information is useful is a matter of taste. Tukey for one thought that it was. You could look at Tukey's explanation in his classic text Exploratory Data Analysis (which this implementation of stem and leaf plots is explicitly trying to follow).